# Combine user-agents in robots.txt

Tags: web-crawlers, robots.txt, user-agent

Can user-agents be listed together, followed by their common rules like so in a *robots.txt*?

```
User-agent: Googlebot
User-agent: ia_archiver #Alexa
User-agent: BingPreview #Microsoft
User-agent: bingbot #Microsoft
User-agent: MSNBot #Microsoft
User-agent: Slurp #Yahoo
User-agent: Ask Jeeves/Teoma #Ask
Disallow: /adm30_buds/
```

Comment: Is there a reason why you don't use `user-agent: *` followed by the disallow? Is the list of "allowed" user-agents longer than the list that you want to disallow?

Comment: See also on SO: [Is it possible to list multiple user-agents in one line?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/20294485/1591669)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Yes. Assuming that your agent names are specified correctly, it looks like this should work. Here is a resource if you want to read more. https://developers.google.com/webmasters/control-crawl-index/docs/robots_txt

Comment: The [original robots.txt spec](http://www.robotstxt.org/orig.html) agrees: *"If more than one User-agent field is present the record describes an identical access policy for more than one robot."*